# How to set image from Uri to an Floating Action Button

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, uri, floating-action-button

I am using this https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton for my menu.

i am getting some issues because whenever i try to set OnclickListener method it doesn't work.

```
final FloatingActionMenu menu = (FloatingActionMenu)findViewById(R.id.fam);
    menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hola",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }});
```

I am getting a NullPointerException.

the real problem is that i have two Floating Action buttons,i need to set an image from an uri on one of the fabs, i dont know if the library have its own onclick method, any sugesstion?

```
    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/fam"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    app:fab_colorNormal="#DA4336"
    app:fab_colorPressed="#E75043"
    app:fab_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
    app:menu_shadowColor="#66000000"
    app:menu_showShadow="true">

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/menu_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
        fab:fab_label="Dashboard"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/menu_item2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_facejam"
        fab:fab_label="Salir"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this [page](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/github/clans/fab/sample/MenusFragment.java) from the samples.

Try using `setOnMenuButtonClickListener` instead of `setOnClickListener` , but before that I guess you need to add your fabs with this function `addMenuButton` and set all the listeners.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, i don't know why i didn't see that before.